# How to `diff --name-status` a repository and its submodules?

Tags: javascript, git, isomorphic-git

I assume I would need to use the `walk` API, but I don't know how to detect when the diff is from a submodule and I don't know either how to introspect the diff on that submodules as well.

Starting from this code snippet (adapted from [here](https://isomorphic-git.org/docs/en/snippets#git-diff-name-status-commithash1-commithash2)), how should I do ?

```js
async function getFileStateChanges(commitHash1, commitHash2, dir) {
    return git.walk({
      fs,
      dir,
      trees: [git.TREE({ ref: commitHash1 }), git.TREE({ ref: commitHash2 })],
      map: async function(filepath, trees) {
        if (filepath === '.') {
          return
        }
        for (const tree of trees.filter(Boolean)) {
          const type = await tree!.type()
          // This is where I should include commit type as well ?
          // And what should I do then to instrospect the submodules and diff ? another `walk` ?
          if (type !=='blob') {
            return
          }
        }
  
        const [fromOID, toOID] = await Promise.all(trees.map(tree => tree?.oid()))
        if (fromOID === toOID) {
          return
        }
  
        let type = 'M'
        if (fromOID === undefined) {
          type = 'A'
        } else if (toOID === undefined) {
          type = 'D'
        }

        return `${type}\t${filepath}`
      },
    })
  }
```